# how to match two columns by group in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like d1.

```
d1<-structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), cname = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), recentcname = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("id", "cname", 
"value", "recentcname"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Here my key variables are "id" and "value". For every individual id, I have to find out maximum value record in "value" column and take that corresponding "cname" string into "recentcname" column for that id. If we have two maximum values for one id, we have to take second highest record's "cname" string into "recentcname" column.

Finally my output will be like d2.

```
d2<-structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), cname = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "BB", "CC"), class = "factor"), 
value = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), recentcname = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("AA", "CC"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"cname", "value", "recentcname"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I can do it by splitting dataset by ib. But it is very time consumable. is there any other alternatives for this task. please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
d1$recentcname <- unsplit(lapply(split(d1[,c("value","cname")], d1$id), function(x) {
    rep(tail(x$cname[x$value==max(x$value)],1), nrow(x))
}), d1$id)
```

we basically split the data by ID, then look for the last max value in each subset and repeat that value for each row in the subset. Then we use `unsplit()` to but the values back in the correct order corresponding to `d1`.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. Its very helpfull to me.

Comment: Above syntax is also taking long time to compute for 100000 records. Is there any other methods...please

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
dd = do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d1, d1$id), function(x)tail(x,1)))
names(dd)[2]= 'recentcname'
merge(d1[1:3], dd[1:2])
  id cname value recentcname
1  1    AA     1          AA
2  1    AA     2          AA
3  1    AA     1          AA
4  2    BB     2          CC
5  2    CC     2          CC
6  3    BB     1          CC
7  3    BB     2          CC
8  3    CC     3          CC
9  4    AA     1          AA
```

Comment: If I use this method, I am getting dimension error(i.e., I am getting more record than my actual records).

Comment: For this sample data it is working fine. But when I apply this code on big data i am getting more records.